# Combining Free types

Tags: haskell, monads, free-monad

I've been recently teaching myself about the `Free` monad from the [free](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/free-4.2) package, but I've come across a problem with it.  I would like to have different free monads for different libraries, essentially I would like to build DSLs for different contexts, but I would also like to be able to combine them together.  As an example:

```hs
{-# LANGUAGE DeriveFunctor #-}
module TestingFree where

import Control.Monad.Free

data BellsF x
    = Ring x
    | Chime x
    deriving (Functor, Show)

type Bells = Free BellsF

data WhistlesF x
    = PeaWhistle x
    | SteamWhistle x
    deriving (Functor, Show)

type Whistles = Free WhistlesF

ring :: Bells ()
ring = liftF $ Ring ()

chime :: Bells ()
chime = liftF $ Chime ()

peaWhistle :: Whistles ()
peaWhistle = liftF $ PeaWhistle ()

steamWhistle :: Whistles ()
steamWhistle = liftF $ SteamWhistle ()


playBells :: Bells r -> IO r
playBells (Pure r)         = return r
playBells (Free (Ring x))  = putStrLn "RingRing!" >> playBells x
playBells (Free (Chime x)) = putStr "Ding-dong!" >> playBells x

playWhistles :: Whistles () -> IO ()
playWhistles (Pure _)                = return ()
playWhistles (Free (PeaWhistle x))   = putStrLn "Preeeet!" >> playWhistles x
playWhistles (Free (SteamWhistle x)) = putStrLn "Choo-choo!" >> playWhistles x
```

Now, I would like to be able to create a type `BellsAndWhistles` that allows me to combine the functionality of both `Bells` and `Whistles` without much effort.

Since the problem is combining monads, my first thought was to look at the `Control.Monad.Trans.Free` module for a quick and easy solution.  Unfortunately, there are sparse examples and none showing what I want to do.  Also, it seems that stacking two or more free monads doesn't work, since `MonadFree` has a functional dependency of `m -> f`.  Essentially, I'd like the ability to write code like:

```hs
newtype BellsAndWhistles m a = BellsAndWhistles
    { unBellsAndWhistles :: ???
    } deriving
        ( Functor
        , Monad
        -- Whatever else needed
        )

noisy :: Monad m => BellsAndWhistles m ()
noisy = do
    lift ring
    lift peaWhistle
    lift chime
    lift steamWhistle

play :: BellsAndWhistles IO () -> IO ()
play bellsNwhistles = undefined
```

But in such a way that `Bells` and `Whistles` can exist in separate modules and don't have to know about each others implementations.  The idea is that I can write stand alone modules for different tasks, each implementing its own DSL, and then having a way to combine them into a "larger" DSL as needed.  Is there an easy way to do this?

As a bonus it'd be great to be able to leverage the different `play*` functions that are already written, in such a way that I can swap them out.  I want to be able to use one free interpreter for debug and another in production, and it'd obviously be useful to be able to choose which DSL was being debugged individually.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

This is an answer based off of the paper [Data types à la carte](http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/summary?doi=10.1.1.101.4131), except without type classes.  I recommend reading that paper.

The trick is that instead of writing interpreters for `Bells` and `Whistles`, you define interpreters for their single functor steps, `BellsF` and `WhistlesF`, like this:

```
playBellsF :: BellsF (IO a) -> IO a
playBellsF (Ring  io) = putStrLn "RingRing!"  >> io
playBellsF (Chime io) = putStr   "Ding-dong!" >> io

playWhistlesF :: WhistelsF (IO a) -> IO a
playWhistlesF (PeaWhistle   io) = putStrLn "Preeeet!"   >> io
playWhistlesF (SteamWhistle io) = putStrLn "choo-choo!" >> io
```

If you choose not to combine them, you can just pass them to `Control.Monad.Free.iterM` to get back your original play functions:

```
playBells    :: Bells a    -> IO a
playBells    = iterM playBell

playWhistles :: Whistles a -> IO a
playWhistles = iterM playWhistlesF
```

... however because they deal with single steps they can be combined more easily.  You can define a new combined free monad like this:

```
data BellsAndWhistlesF a = L (BellsF a) | R (WhistlesF a)
```

Then turn that into a free monad:

```
type BellsAndWhistles = Free BellsAndWhistlesF
```

Then you write an interpreter for a single step of `BellsAndWhistlesF` in terms of the two sub-interpreters:

```
playBellsAndWhistlesF :: BellsAndWhistlesF (IO a) -> IO a
playBellsAndWhistlesF (L bs) = playBellsF    bs
playBellsAndWhistlesF (R ws) = playWhistlesF ws
```

... and then you get the interpreter for the free monad by just passing that to `iterM`:

```
playBellsAndWhistles :: BellsAndWhistles a -> IO a
playBellsAndWhistles = iterM playBellsAndWhistlesF
```

So the answer to your question is that the trick to combining free monads is to preserve more information by defining intermediate interpreters for individual functor steps ("algebras").  These "algebras" are much more amenable to combination than interpreters for free monads.

Comment: When I tried to solve this problem earlier today, I originally attempted a sum type as `data Dual a b = L a | R b` and added the appropriate `Functor` instance, but I couldn't get the types to quite line up.  This seems like a good solution, but I also have the issue that I could have 3 or more functors to combine.  Do you think it'd be more efficient to stack types like `BellsAndWhistlesF` (@LuisCasillas used the name `Sum`) or to make a custom ADT with the number of elements I need for each situation?  That sounds like it'd have a lot of excess boilerplate, though.

Comment: @bheklilr In my experience it is easier to make a custom ADT to unify all your functors than to nest the sum type.

Comment: @GabrielGonzalez Instead of combining the functors using sum types and then using a single free monad, would it be a good idea to use multiple layers of `FreeT` transformers, one for each functor? I have sometimes used nested layers of pipes' `Producers` for that purpose.

Comment: Yes, you can do that.  Just keep in mind that nested `FreeT`s are not exactly the same thing (they are not isomorphic to the equivalent version using sum types), but it's probably good enough for most purposes.

Answer (score 18):

Gabriel's answer is spot on, but I think it pays to highlight a bit more the thing that makes it all work, which is that **the sum of two `Functor`s is also a `Functor`**:

```
-- | Data type to encode the sum of two 'Functor's @f@ and @g@.
data Sum f g a = InL (f a) | InR (g a)

-- | The 'Sum' of two 'Functor's is also a 'Functor'.
instance (Functor f, Functor g) => Functor (Sum f g) where
    fmap f (InL fa) = InL (fmap f fa)
    fmap f (InR ga) = InR (fmap f ga)

-- | Elimination rule for the 'Sum' type.
elimSum :: (f a -> r) -> (g a -> r) -> Sum f g a -> r
elimSum f _ (InL fa) = f fa
elimSum _ g (InR ga) = g ga
```

(Edward Kmett's libraries have this as [`Data.Functor.Coproduct`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/comonad-transformers-3.0.4/docs/Data-Functor-Coproduct.html).)

So if `Functor`s are the "instruction sets" for `Free` monads, then:

1. Sum functors give you the *unions* of such instruction sets, and thus the corresponding combined free monads
2. The `elimSum` function is the basic rule that allows you to build a `Sum f g` interpreter out of an interpreter for `f` and one for `g`.

The ["Data types *à la carte*"](http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/summary?doi=10.1.1.101.4131) techniques are just what you get when you develop this insight—it's well worth your while to just work it out by hand.

This kind of `Functor` algebra is a valuable thing to learn.  For example:

```
data Product f g a = Product (f a) (g a)

-- | The 'Product' of two 'Functor's is also a 'Functor'.
instance (Functor f, Functor g) => Functor (Product f g) where
   fmap f (Product fa ga) = Product (fmap f fa) (fmap f ga)

-- | The 'Product' of two 'Applicative's is also an 'Applicative'.
instance (Applicative f, Applicative g) => Applicative (Product f g) where
   pure x = Product (pure x) (pure x)
   Product ff gf <*> Product fa ga = Product (ff <*> fa) (gf <*> ga)


-- | 'Compose' is to 'Applicative' what monad transformers are to 'Monad'.
-- If your problem domain doesn't need the full power of the 'Monad' class, 
-- then applicative composition might be a good alternative on how to combine
-- effects.
data Compose f g a = Compose (f (g a))

-- | The composition of two 'Functor's is also a 'Functor'.
instance (Functor f, Functor g) => Functor (Compose f g) where
   fmap f (Compose fga) = Compose (fmap (fmap f) fga)

-- | The composition of two 'Applicative's is also an 'Applicative'.
instance (Applicative f, Applicative g) => Applicative (Compose f g) where
   pure = Compose . pure . pure
   Compose fgf <*> Compose fga = Compose ((<*>) <$> fgf <*> fga)
```

Gershom Bazerman's blog entry ["Abstracting with `Applicative`s"](http://comonad.com/reader/2012/abstracting-with-applicatives/) expands on these points about `Applicative`s, and is very well worth reading.

---

**EDIT:** One final thing I'll note is that when people design their custom `Functor`s for their free monads, in fact, implicitly they're using precisely these techniques.  I'll take two examples from Gabriel's ["Why free monads matter"](http://www.haskellforall.com/2012/06/you-could-have-invented-free-monads.html):

```
data Toy b next =
    Output b next
  | Bell next
  | Done

data Interaction next =
    Look Direction (Image -> next)
  | Fire Direction next
  | ReadLine (String -> next)
  | WriteLine String (Bool -> next)
```

All of these can be analyzed into some combination of the `Product`, `Sum`, `Compose`, `(->)` functors and the following three:

```
-- | Provided by "Control.Applicative"
newtype Const b a = Const b

instance Functor (Const b) where
    fmap _ (Const b) = Const b


-- | Provided by "Data.Functor.Identity"
newtype Identity a = Identity a

instance Functor Identity where
    fmap f (Identity a) = Identity (f a)


-- | Near-isomorphic to @Const ()@
data VoidF a = VoidF

instance Functor VoidF where
    fmap _ VoidF = VoidF
```

So using the following type synonyms for brevity:

```
{-# LANGUAGE TypeOperators #-}

type f :+: g = Sum f g
type f :*: g = Product f g
type f :.: g = Compose f g

infixr 6 :+:
infixr 7 :*:
infixr 9 :.:
```

...we can rewrite those functors like this:

```
type Toy b = Const b :*: Identity :+: Identity :+: VoidF

type Interaction = Const Direction :*: ((->) Image :.: Identity)
               :+: Const Direction :*: Identity
               :+: (->) String :.: Identity
               :+: Const String :*: ((->) Bool :.: Identity)
```

Comment: This is fine for just two functors, but what about 3 or more?  Would it be more advantageous to write my own `data Sum3 f g h = L f | C g | R h`, or the equivalent `Sum4`, or just apply `Sum` repeatedly?

Comment: Also, while it's good to know about `Compose`, for my particular application I definitely need IO, the DSLs I am writing are actually for controlling external equipment over serial and VISA.

Comment: @bheklilr: For the 3-or-more case, I recommend you read the "Data types *à la carte*" paper and see if you like their type class-based solution. On the other question, the fact that you need IO doesn't mean you can't use `Applicative`, since `IO` is an instance of that class too. `Applicative` doesn't prevent you from having `IO`—what it does is restrict how you *combine* the `IO` actions.

Comment: I was able to implement exactly what I wanted using the examples shown in Data Types a la Carte, thanks!  It blows me away sometimes how powerful the Haskell type system can be.  However, I did end up having to write much of the underlying types myself (copy/pasted from the paper).  Does ekmett have the `:+:`, `:<:`, and other associated types implemented somewhere?

Comment: @bheklilr You may be interested in the compdata package (http://hackage.haskell.org/package/compdata). See Data.Comp.Ops.