# "Data types à la carte" vs. nested FreeT transformers

Tags: haskell, monads

In the comments to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21395407/combining-free-types), it has been mentioned that nesting several layers of [FreeT](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/free-4.2/docs/Control-Monad-Trans-Free.html#v:FreeT) transformers (each with a different functor) can serve a similar purpose to the ["Data types à la carte"](http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/summary?doi=10.1.1.101.4131) approach (that combines the functors themselves using coproducts) despite the two approaches not being isomorphic.

My question is: where does the difference lie? Are there cases that one approach can handle, but not the other? Do they admit different interpreters?

**Update:** Here's a simple example of nested `FreeT` transformers. Augmenting a computation with the ability to emit log messages and request delays:

```
import Data.Functor.Identity
import Control.Monad
import Control.Monad.Trans
import Control.Monad.Trans.Free
import Control.Concurrent

type Delay = Int

type DelayT = FreeT ((,) Delay)

delay ::  Monad m => Delay -> DelayT m ()
delay t = liftF (t,()) 

type Message = String

type LogT = FreeT ((,) Message)

emitLog :: Monad m => Message -> LogT m ()
emitLog msg = liftF (msg,()) 

type Effected = DelayT (LogT Identity)

program :: Effected Char
program = lift (emitLog "foo") >> delay 1000 >> return 'c'

interpret :: Effected a -> IO a 
interpret =                          (iterT $ \(d,a)->threadDelay d >> a)  
            . hoistFreeT             (iterT $ \(m,a)->putStrLn m >> a) 
            . hoistFreeT (hoistFreeT (return . runIdentity))

main :: IO ()
main = interpret program >>= putChar
```

(This particular example could have been made even simpler by using `Producer`s from the `pipes` package, which are a particular kind of free monad transformers.)

Comment: This is, as I understand, an ongoing debate in the Haskell community. See, for example, Kiselyov, Sabry & Swords' ["Extensible Effects: An Alternative to Monad Transformers"](http://www.cs.indiana.edu/~sabry/papers/exteff.pdf) (PDF), and the resulting discussions in [Lambda The Ultimate](http://lambda-the-ultimate.org/node/4786) and [/r/haskell in Reddit](http://www.reddit.com/r/haskell/comments/1j9n5y/extensible_effects_an_alternative_to_monad/).

Comment: @LuisCasillas Would "Extensible Effects" correspond to the nested `FreeT` approach, or to "Datatypes à la carte"?

Comment: I believe it corresponds to "Datatypes à la carte," but I'm not 100% certain. In any case, if I'm reading this right [emkett said Extensible Effects ~= Datatypes à la carte + open unions](http://www.reddit.com/r/haskell/comments/1j9n5y/extensible_effects_an_alternative_to_monad/cbcwbsa).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'm not 100% confident in my own understanding of this, so if anyone notices anything (blatantly) wrong, please point it out.

Starting with Extensible Effects, the `Eff` type is basically isomorphic to:

```
data Eff :: [* -> *] -> * -> * where
    Pure :: a -> Eff es a
    Side :: Union es (Eff es a) -> Eff es a
```

where `Union es a` is a union/sum type of the list of types `es` parameterized by `a`. `Union` is isomorphic to repeated applications of `:+:` from Data Types a la Carte. To sum (!) it all up, `Eff` seems to be an optimized version of Data Types a la Carte.

We may conclude that the differences between monad transformers and extensible effects described in the paper apply here. In particular, free monad transformer stacks cannot interleave effects, while Data Types a la Carte/Extensible Effects can.