# Handling ambiguous types in composable free DSLs

Tags: haskell, free-monad

I'm building a couple of DSLs which should be composable based on 'free monads' and 'datatypes a la carte', using the *free* and *compdata* packages (similar in spirit to [Combining Free types](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21395407/combining-free-types)).

Whilst this works for some simple DSLs, I'm stuck on one which has a type parameter, in the case of a constructor/command which doesn't depend on this type parameter, causing an *ambiguous type parameter* error from GHC.

To clarify, here's some code:

```
{-# LANGUAGE DeriveFunctor #-}
{-# LANGUAGE FlexibleContexts #-}
{-# LANGUAGE TypeOperators #-}

module DSL where

import Data.Comp
import Control.Monad.Free

type Index = Int

data DSL a next = Read Index (a -> next)
                | Write a (Index -> next)
                | GetLastIndex (Index -> next)
    deriving (Functor)

read :: (Functor f, DSL a :<: f, MonadFree f m) => Index -> m a
read idx = liftF (inj (Read idx id))

write :: (Functor f, DSL a :<: f, MonadFree f m) => a -> m Index
write a = liftF (inj (Write a id))

-- This works
getLastIndex' :: MonadFree (DSL a) m => m Index
getLastIndex' = liftF (GetLastIndex id)

-- This doesn't:
--
--     Could not deduce (Data.Comp.Ops.Subsume
--                         (compdata-0.10:Data.Comp.SubsumeCommon.ComprEmb
--                            (Data.Comp.Ops.Elem (DSL a0) f))
--                         (DSL a0)
--                         f)
--     from the context (Functor f, DSL a :<: f, MonadFree f m)
--       bound by the type signature for
--                  getLastIndex :: (Functor f, DSL a :<: f, MonadFree f m) => m Index
--       at simple.hs:30:17-66
--     The type variable ‘a0’ is ambiguous
--     In the ambiguity check for the type signature for ‘getLastIndex’:
--       getLastIndex :: forall (m :: * -> *) (f :: * -> *) a.
--                       (Functor f, DSL a :<: f, MonadFree f m) =>
--                       m Index
--     To defer the ambiguity check to use sites, enable AllowAmbiguousTypes
--     In the type signature for ‘getLastIndex’:
--       getLastIndex :: (Functor f, DSL a :<: f, MonadFree f m) => m Index

getLastIndex :: (Functor f, DSL a :<: f, MonadFree f m) => m Index
-- getLastIndex = liftF (inj (GetLastIndex id))
getLastIndex = _
```

Trying to get this to work with enabling the *AllowAmbiguousTypes* extension as hinted by GHC didn't get me any further. I tried adding some *forall a*-style things in the type signature, to no avail.

Is there any way to get this pattern to work?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is a relatively well-known limitation of open sums "à la Carte".

In short, if we have an `f` functor that itself has one or more inner type indices, then type inference suffers significantly for open sums containing that functor.

Illustrating the reasons, suppose we have an open sum that contains a `DSL ()` and a `DSL Int`. GHC must pick an instance for one of them, but it's impossible with `getLastIndex`, because the `a` parameter isn't mentioned in the arguments or the return type. GHC has essentially no information about `a` from the context.

This can be remedied in a somewhat clumsy way using `Data.Proxy`:

```
import Data.Proxy

getLastIndex ::
  forall a f m.
  (Functor f, DSL a :<: f, MonadFree f m)
  => Proxy a -> m Index
getLastIndex _ = liftF (inj (GetLastIndex id :: DSL a Index))
```

Alternatively, we can recover nice type inference and unambiguity if we require that there is only a single `DSL` in the open sum. However, this
involves rewriting the type-level lookup code for `:<:` for functors like `DSL` (those that have an inner type index). We can't really do this with `compdata` as it is, because it doesn't export the relevant [type-level machinery.](https://github.com/pa-ba/compdata/blob/master/src/Data/Comp/SubsumeCommon.hs)

I wrote a [minimal example](https://gist.github.com/AndrasKovacs/98787f19fce22be025ab) for what the implementation of the above looks like for your case. I don't paste it here because it's a bit long and unedifying. Note that the choice of the inner index becomes completely determined by the functor's constructor and the open sum. This also repairs type inference for other cases; for example with the old code we have to type-annotate every use of `Write x f` if `x` is a number literal or any polymorphic value, while in the new code its gets inferred.

Also, note that the example implementation is only for functors with a single inner index! If we'd like to have a `DSL a b next`, then we would have to write new code for that case too, or use `DSL '(a, b) next` instead.

Comment: I had just worked out that this was what Haskell was complaining about but your answer is much more satisfactory than the two paragraphs I'd written about the subject. Awesomely said, cheers.

Comment: Thanks for the thorough answer! The part explaining why 'DSL a' would be unresolvable makes sense, and requiring 'some' DSL layer would make sense as well, but now I'm unable to define 'read' or 'write' using your example code...

Comment: @NicolasTrangez I edited my linked example. You can find `read` and `write` there now. We use `IxOf DSL f` instead of the `a` parameter in the types.